# How to add a different alpha to every bar depending on Y axis "height"

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, alpha

I would want to add alpha to my bar plot (ggplot2) but per bar I want a different alpha and it should be depended on the y axis height.
I am not too experienced with r so I am still struggling :) My code so far is this.
Correct choice was binomial distributed and with just 1 or 0 noted.

```
#Data preparation#
DataMerged235$treatment <- factor(DataMerged235$treatment, levels = c("odour & flavour", "only odour", "only flavour"))

#Figure#
 fig235 <- ggplot (DataMerged235, aes(x = treatment, y = correct_final)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar", fill="dodgerblue4") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", geom="errorbar", width = 0.2) +
  ylab("Proportion of correct choices") + xlab("") + theme_bw(16) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0.5, slope = 0, color = "black", linetype = 2) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.4, 1.15))

 print(fig235)
```

Here the current output: https://ibb.co/mHVSwpt

I would want to add that higher y max of the bar means darker alpha. Which would result, in our example, to a decreased alpha (left to right).

A random part from my data:

```
structure(list(colony = c(14, 5, 12, 11, 12, 14, 12, 18, 12, 
12), correct_initial = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), correct_final = c(1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), treatment = c("odour & flavour", 
"only odour", "odour & flavour", "only odour", "odour & flavour", 
"odour & flavour", "odour & flavour", "only flavour", "only flavour", 
"odour & flavour")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Interesting question - I do not know the answer yet, however I believe the functions `after_stat()` or `after_scale()` will play a role in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out how to do this inside the `stat_summary` line, but an alternate approach would be to pre-calculate the stats you want to use.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    group_by(gear) %>%
    summarize(mean = mean(mpg),
              stats = mean_cl_boot(mpg), .groups = "drop") -> mtcars_stats
> mtcars_stats
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   gear  mean stats$y $ymin $ymax
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3  16.1    16.1  14.4  17.7
2     4  24.5    24.5  21.8  27.4
3     5  21.4    21.4  16.3  26.6
```

Then it's straightforward:

```
ggplot(aes(gear, mean, ymin = stats$ymin, ymax = stats$ymax)) +
  geom_col(fill = "dodgerblue4", aes(alpha = mean)) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.2)
```

[image]

Edit - updated using new example data from OP:

```
DataMerged235 %>%
    mutate(treatment = factor(treatment, levels = c("odour & flavour", "only odour", "only flavour"))) %>%
    group_by(treatment) %>%
    summarize(mean = mean(correct_final),
              stats = mean_cl_boot(correct_final), .groups = "drop") %>%
    ggplot(aes(treatment, mean, ymin = stats$ymin, ymax = stats$ymax)) +
    geom_col(fill = "dodgerblue4", aes(alpha = mean)) +
    geom_errorbar(width = 0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it but got 2 error msg. "Warning in mean.default(DataMerged235) " Argument is not numeric nor boolean." and cant combine colony (double) and treatment (factor dde1b)  I added a  part of my data to the original post.

Comment: It seems to work on the provided sample. If it doesn't work on your full data, see if you can share a sample that also breaks.

Comment: Thank you very much :)! It worked! I would upward your answers but I dont have 15 priveleg so far.

Comment: `+ guides(alpha = "none")` and something like `scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.4, 1), trans = "sqrt" )` which would give control both over the range of alpha values as well as whether the alpha changes more sharply at the bottom or top of the range.

Comment: Thank you very much :)!